# Associated Domains with `applinks:` is not working in development

Tags: ios

I'm trying to set up [Associated Domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains) in my unpublished app for iOS 14. I followed the documentation as good as possible. I'm testing locally with my local dev web server and the app itself in simulator and a real iPhone.

Not only are links not opening in my app, the app does not even attempt to request the file `https://mycomputer.local/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` from my local web server (I let the web server print a debug message whenever it is requested, but the message is only printed when I manually load it from a web browser).

This is a list of things I have done/checked:

- Xcode 12.2:

  - *Under Signing & Capabilities* added *Associated Domains*
  - Added to Domains: `applinks:mycomputer.local?mode=developer` (I also tried IP address)
  - I disabled *Automatically manage signing* and instead created a Profile on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list (type *Development*, platform *iOS*, it has *Associated Domains* amongst other enabled capabilities and it's linked to my app bundle ID) and selected that profile for the debug build.
- I made sure that the URL `https://mycomputer.local/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` is accessible from all devices involved, i.e. my computer, Safari in simulator, Safari on real iPhone (all are connected to the local network and successfully display my JSON file).

Screenshot:
[image]

As mentioned above, I can pretty much rule out that the problem lies with the JSON file itself as I can proof that the device is not even accessing it. Am I missing something or misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: IP address will not work also remove any query parameters in the domain added in capabilities.

Comment: can you also try to have a copy of the file in the root directory of your webserver? I am not sure whether local domains will be crawled by Apple so it is missing the domain completely.

Comment: @Satheesh Thanks. I made the JSON available on root, too, but it's also not being accessed from there. The query parameter is supposed to do exactly that, avoid the Apple CDN in order to make private servers work, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains

Comment: Do you have any valid SSL certificate installed on your local webserver? If not, try adding the `App Transport Security Settings` entitlement to your Info.plist with the `Allow arbitrary loads` key set to YES.

Comment: @RainerSchwarz Thanks, but yes, I've got an accepted certificate, but also have the settings you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

My own answer: Using the query string `?mode=developer` in the entitlement as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) simply appears not to work at all.

To verify this I have set up a real server that can be publicly reached on the internet and tried both variants:

1. `applinks:example.com`
2. `applinks:example.com?mode=developer`

Number 1 works, but the JSON is loaded via Apple's CDN and you cannot use it for local development or for quickly testing different versions of the JSON file as Apple will cache the file for probably one day.

Number 2 does not work at all, no request to the server will be made.

Comment: Home come they make this sooooo damn complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Also, good to know these requirements when testing on actual devices. (And using a domain thats not publicly available in testing period.)

- Turn on Developer Mode on the device.
- Turn on Associated Domains Development in the Developer settings. (Developer settings will first occur after you have turned on Developer Mode).
- Build the app using developer certificate. (Enterprise will not work).
- Add ?mode=developer to the domain in entitlements if you are testing with a domain thats not publicly available (Behind VPN..)